# Turbo Pascal 3.0 compile from command-line

Tags: command-line, dos, turbo-pascal

Is it possible to compile (to a COM file) from the command-line using Turbo Pascal 3.0? No matter what arguments I try with TURBO it launches the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to upgrade to [Turbo Pascal 5](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/turbopascal?cid=701G0000000tKTx), which has TPC.EXE, the commandline tool. Turbo Pascal 3.02 only has TURBO.COM.